# SciPy LeastSq - Array to Scalar Issue

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use scipy.leastsq() as a method of finding a best fit point to a set of data. Unfamiliar with the scipy library, I get the impression that the leastsq function does math on the entire set of data at once, yet at the same time I'm having issues because it seems to be taking some data points as a scalar.

My goal is to get the result as a set of two values - aka a point (x,y) with the minimum distance to a series of circles, which are also given to the leastsq function in the form of (x,y,radius). The math in the first half of the leastsq function finds the point on each circle closest to the guess, and then gets the distance from the guess to that point.

Call to the leastsq function (xi, yi, radii are already loaded with values into the array)

```
#Now that we have the center, we can do least squares
#generate point guess starting at avg of circles
ptGuess = np.array([avgX,avgY])         
point, cov,info,mesg, ier = optimize.leastsq(calcResiduals, ptGuess, args = (xi,yi,radii))
```

And calcResiduals():

```
def calcResiduals(ptGuess, xi, yi, radii):
#extract x and y from guess point
xg = ptGuess[0]
yg = ptGuess[1]
#slope of the line from (xi,yi) to guess (xg,yg)
m = (yg - yi) / (xg - xi)
#Go along the line for the distance of c to get coordinates
deltax = radii / math.sqrt(1+m**2)
if (xi > xg):
    xii = xi + deltax
else:
    xii = xi - deltax
yii = m*(xii-xi) + yi
#residuals is distance from (xii,yii) to (xg, yg)
return (xii-xg)**2 + (yii-yg)**2
```

The error I get seems to hint at an issue with converting the array to a scalar value for multiplication, but I don't know why that line would not work yet the previous one would.

Error:

```
File "listener.py", line 62, in calcAPLocation
point, cov,info,mesg, ier = optimize.leastsq(calcResiduals, ptGuess, args = (xi,yi,radii))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 276, in leastsq
m = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 13, in _check_func
res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
File "listener.py", line 76, in calcResiduals
deltax = radii / math.sqrt(1+m**2)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If xi and yi in your code are arrays of points, then m should be an array with length equal
to len(xi).  The function math.sqrt needs arrays with a length of 1 or scalars to work.

The previous line:

```
m = (yg - yi) / (xg - xi)
```

works because you're dividing to arrays of the same length.

This line fails:

```
deltax = radii / math.sqrt(1+m**2)
```

because m is an array with many entries, and the python math library doesn't know how to handle it.  You could try changing math.sqrt to numpy.sqrt to take the square root of each
entry in m.  I think this is what you're after.  Change the above line to

```
deltaX = radii/np.sqrt(1 + m**2)
```